# Can I connect to a localhost WebSocket while being offline, i.e. without having internet connection?

Tags: javascript, websocket, localhost, offline

This is a Javascript question.

while having no internet connection, if I run

```
new WebSocket('ws://localhost:watheverPort')
```

or

```
new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:watheverPort')
```

in a web browser, do I get connected to  the WebSocket?

To me it is would be a bit strange, since I do not have a "Web" on top of which my "Web"Socket would be accessible.

Comment: isn't there anything in the the console

Comment: no, anything. I really think the browser will wait forever

Comment: check `WebSockets` in the `Network`

Comment: you mean in the documentation? The websocket is active and working. I have tested with another application

Comment: No in chrome DevTools (firefox and edge too) you will find `network` next to `console` and `sources`

Comment: if The websocket is active and working then what are what are you waiting for specifically? a message from the server? I mean what is supposed to happen

Comment: Sorry to all of you, pleople. The websocket was working. So the answer to my question is just 'YES'!